# plotting lines with dataframes of different lengths

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I want to plot lines for the three dataframes `df1`, `df2`, `df3` which are of different lengths with `col1` on `x-axis`, `col2` on `y-axis`.

```
 # Data
 set.seed(123)
 df1<-data.frame(col1=sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10, replace=FALSE), col2=sample(c(1:26),10))
 > df1
    col1 col2
 1     C   25
 2     H   12
 3     D   17
 4     G   14
 5     F    3
 6     A   19
 7     J    5
 8     I    1
 9     B    6
 10    E   24

 df2 <- data.frame(col1=sample(LETTERS[1:10], 5, replace=FALSE), col2=sample(c(1:26),5))
> df2
   col1 col2
 1    I   19
 2    G   14
 3    F   15
 4    J    7
 5    D    4

df3 <- data.frame(col1=sample(LETTERS[1:10], 8, replace=FALSE), col2=sample(c(1:26),8))
 > df3
   col1 col2
 1    J    9
 2    I    6
 3    F    4
 4    H   10
 5    A   23
 6    C    8
 7    D   24
 8    G    3

 # plotting
 lab.min <- min(c(df2$col2, df1$col2, df3$col2), na.rm = T)
 lab.max <- max(c(df2$col2, df1$col2, df3$col2), na.rm = T)
 plot(df1$col1, df1$col2, type='o', pch=0, las=2, ylim=c(lab.min, lab.max))
 lines(df2$col1, df2$col2, type='o', pch=2)
 lines(df3$col1, df3$col2, type='o', pch=8)
 # add a legend 
 legend(0, 20, c('df1','df2','df3'), cex=0.8, pch=c(0,2,8), title="df")
 abline(h=5)
```

[image]

From the plot, I could observe that the lines are not taking same col1 values from all the dataframes. All the three dataframe have value `J` in `col1`, but the plot shows only the value from `df1`. Could you please advise on how to overcome this ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your desired output is? It is unclear to me what you mean with 'the lines are not taking the col1 values alike`. Is the representation for df1 wrong, or for df2 and df3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `col1` is a factor, so when it is plotted, the integer representation of the factor is used as the x value.  To fix this, make sure that all `col1` variables have the same factor levels, and thus the same underlying integer.

```
set.seed(123)
df1<-data.frame(col1=sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10, replace=FALSE), col2=sample(c(1:26),10))
df2 <- data.frame(col1=sample(LETTERS[1:10], 5, replace=FALSE), col2=sample(c(1:26),5))
df3 <- data.frame(col1=sample(LETTERS[1:10], 8, replace=FALSE), col2=sample(c(1:26),8))

## Put the data.frames in a list, and convert col1 to have same levels
dfs <- lapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:3)), function(x)
    transform(x, col1=factor(col1, levels=LETTERS[1:10])))

## Put data.frames back into global environment
## Note: I only do this to reuse your code, but it would be better
## to keep them in a list
list2env(dfs, .GlobalEnv)

## plotting
lab.min <- min(c(df2$col2, df1$col2, df3$col2), na.rm = T)
lab.max <- max(c(df2$col2, df1$col2, df3$col2), na.rm = T)
plot(df1$col1, df1$col2, type='o', pch=0, las=2, ylim=c(lab.min, lab.max))
lines(df2$col1, df2$col2, type='o', pch=2)
lines(df3$col1, df3$col2, type='o', pch=8)
                                        # add a legend 
legend(0, 20, c('df1','df2','df3'), cex=0.8, pch=c(0,2,8), title="df")
abline(h=5)
```

[image]

This could also be fixed by explicitly setting the factor levels when you initially created your data.

Comment: I have explicitly set the levels of the `col1` as `levels(df1$col1) <- LETTERS[1:10]` for all the dfs. Unfortunately, I plot remain the same. How to identify what values, the plot/lines is taking while plotting ?

Comment: @Prradep but that won't work - it will make all your factors start from 1, do what I did in the code above to fix the factors.  You can see the integer by doing `as.integer(yourFactor)`

Comment: Thanks for your advise. My real dfs are not like these so, I have to figure out the equivalent for your approach. I managed to rectify my earlier approach using `df1$col1 <- factor(df1$col1, levels =  LETTERS[1:10])` Thanks, I will follow both of them based on my need. Would you suggest, how to make these lines look good, I mean to reorder the points to be considered while drawing lines(A,B,C,D...) ?

Comment: @Prradep if you use `sort` or `order` to sort your data prior to `lines`, the points should be connected in order.